# How to use jQuery to remove tags and all text between said tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code that is as follows:

```
<p class="fp-excerpt fp-text-one  text-random-override">[image caption]I don't want this text[/image caption]Lorem Ipsum Text</p>

<p class="fp-excerpt fp-text-one  text-random-override">[image caption]I don't want the text here too[/image caption]Lorem Ipsum Text number two</p>
```

How do I use jQuery to target the paragraph class and remove the [image caption] and [/image caption] tags, as well as the random text in between?

Thank you!

Comment: your JS  code  ??????

Comment: just add a class on that tag and remove the said class

Comment: [image caption] tag does not have a class and it is produced by a plugin that I'm not able to edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$(".text-random-override").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\[image caption\].+\[\/image caption\]/g,""));
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s293gL2k/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <style>
       .check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check {
  font-weight: bold;
}

    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('p.text-random-override').each(function () {

            var szData = $(this).text();

            szData = szData.replace(/((.)*)(\[image caption\])((.)*)(\[\/image caption\])((.)*)/g, "$7");

            $(this).text(szData)
        });

    });


</script>
</head>
<body>

  <p class="fp-excerpt fp-text-one  text-random-override">[image caption]I don't want this text[/image caption]Lorem Ipsum Text</p>

<p class="fp-excerpt fp-text-one  text-random-override">[image caption]I don't want the text here too[/image caption]Lorem Ipsum Text number two</p>


</html>
```